# Overshoe for Specialized Sport MTB Shoe

Tags: shoes

At the recommendation of my local bike megastore, I bought Endura Luminate overshoes. Sadly, they are letting water in through the front as they are not a particularly good comparable shape with the shoes.

Anyone running these shoes have luck with a particular overshoes?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE! Please refrain from asking questions that involve product recommendation. As they are very open ended and result in a plethora of opinionated answers (and product recommendations aren't allowed for this reason) and generally result in being closed. Consider rewording.

Comment: I haven't worn overshoes for about 15 years now, but I used to have a pair of fully rubberized ones with no seams (from Performance, I'm guessing).  However, they still leaked because one had to cut a hole in the bottom for the cleat.  They were better than nothing in 20-degree slush, but "warm" and "dry" were only theories.

Comment: With Mavic, shoes and overshoes from the same brand fit together like they had been designed to do so. I would guess other brands do that too.

Answer (score 1):

After many years of riding in foul weather, I rarely use overshoes for above freezing temperatures.  They are NEVER waterproof.  The opening for your cleat and heel allows water into the setup which inevitably makes it's way up to your ventilated upper.  For them to actually be waterproof, they would need to seal to the bottom sole of your shoe.  Additionally, the cleat attachment area of your shoe would need to be waterproof (many are not).  More than occasional walking tends to wear them prematurely.  I've owned several brands and never had a set make it through more than three seasons (fall, spring and perhaps part of another fall) before they are coming apart at the seams.

Several companies make foul weather shoes.  They range from truly insulated winter boots to versions of the companies regular offerings with no ventilation holes and a sealed bottom around the cleat area.  I've had several pairs of these from various companies and all have lasted longer than 4 seasons (2 years).

In my opinion overshoes are only appropriate as an insulation layer when it's too cold to be wet or when you are a pro doing a time trial and they extra 0.75 seconds they afford are worth it (they are free from your sponsor at that point anyway).

Comment: Sounds like you didn't have much luck with your overshoe choice.  Whilst I agree they are never fully waterproof i'm on 3 pairs out of 3 that only let in water if you submerge your feet.  I don't actually consider waterproofing as too important for an overshoe though, wind-proof with wool socks keeps feet warm even when wet.

Comment: For ventilated shoes, overshoes do a good job of keeping a cold wind off your feet. I bought some *non*-insulated ones for winter use, but I've only been cold enough to need them in the dry

Comment: @ChrisH I agree with that, except that it doesn't make sense financially (to me).  A set of winter shoes will also be windproof and work well when it is wet.

Comment: @AndyP For some period of time yes, but I wouldn't want to spin in wet wool socks for three hours.  Additionally, I don't want to spin that extra water weight if I don't have too.  Most of my serious riding is endurance, so I tend to favor solutions that will work for the long haul.

Comment: @SuspendedUser I can see the sense in that, though I've had shoes fill with water while riding.